# Progress Bar is visible in other browsers but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, progress-bar

I am trying to implement a progress bar (with bootstrap), when I am uploading Files to my Server.
Other Browsers like Chrome or Edge do show the progress bar, just Firefox not.
This is my Code:

```
 <div class="progress">
 <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
 </div>
```

```
<script>
    function startUpload() {
        var progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
        progressBar.style.width = '0%';

        var form = document.getElementById('upload-form');
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "{{ url_for('daten') }}");
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
            var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
            progressBar.style.width = percent + '%';
            }
        });

        xhr.send(formData);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible to share a working fiddle?

Comment: Program works with Flask, idk if I can share a fiddle

Comment: what are the css properties for the .progress container?